# Quitar ancho completo a fieldset

Tags: html, css

Buen dia, tengo un detalle con un fieldset que no logro resolver, he puesto nombre de clase al fieldset y al form con padding y width pero sigue haciendo el fieldset responsive, y quiero tenerlo fijo que no sea responsive.

```css
.frmingreso {
 padding-right: 80px;
}
input {
 padding: 12px 20px;
 margin: 8px 0;
 display: inline-block;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 4px;
 box-sizing: border-box; 
}

.btnenviar {
    background-color: white; 
    color: black; 
    border: 2px solid #4CAF50;
}

.btnenviar:hover {
    background-color: #59BDF2;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="frmingreso">
   <form action"login.php" method="POST">
    Usuario:<br>
    <input type="text" name="usuario"><br>
    Contraseña:<br>
    <input type="text" name="contrasena"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="btnenviar" value="Entrar" class="btnenviar">
</fieldset>
```

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con **tenerlo fijo en lugar de responsive**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El truco es [la propiedad display](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9189873/4987172), puedes utilizar inline o inline-block.

```css
.frmingreso {
 padding-right: 80px;
    border: 2px solid #3F4;
    display: inline-block;
}
input {
 padding: 12px 20px;
 margin: 8px 0;
 display: inline-block;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 4px;
 box-sizing: border-box; 
}

.btnenviar {
    background-color: white; 
    color: black; 
    border: 2px solid #4CAF50;
}

.btnenviar:hover {
    background-color: #59BDF2;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="frmingreso">
 <form action"login.php" method="POST">
  Usuario:<br>
  <input type="text" name="usuario"><br>
  Contraseña:<br>
  <input type="text" name="contrasena"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="btnenviar" value="Entrar" class="btnenviar">
 </form>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, es lo que buscaba adaptare tu codigo a mi aplicacion, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Le puedes definir el ancho de la siguiente forma

```
.frmingreso{
  width: 180px;
}
```

ver link: https://codepen.io/mpita/pen/ZJBRyB

Comment: Si bien el enlace indicado puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!